# How to use a dynamic import in a firebase cloud function using Javascript

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, es6-modules

How can I make this work without having the pre-deploy linter produce an error? If I disable the linter will it work on the cloud? (It works with my mocha tests).

```
async function() {
      const { ChatGPTAPI } = await import('chatgpt');
}
```

> 29:32  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token import
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Setting type: "module" in package.json produces error with the eslintrc.js

Comment: It seems like your linter doesn't support es imports?

Comment: Are you using Javascript or Typescript? Also, please edit the question and add eslintrc file.

Comment: @Dharmaraj the title is literally "using Javascript" :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's the default linter for firebase functions

Comment: Do firebase functions support es modules?

Comment: Best to confirm as many just use JS tag around :D Anyways, can you please share eslint file? Firebase supports ES6 syntax with TS only iirc.